# Three.js screen width

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have code

```
let ADD = 0.01;
const animate = function () {
     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
     mesh.position.x += ADD;
         if (mesh.position.x <= -3 || mesh.position.x >= 3) {
          ADD *= -1;
     }
     renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
```

in this example my mesh moves to the left 3 and to the right 3 but i need move mesh to full width.
if console.log(window.innerWidth)  = 2560(my resolution)

How can i get screen width in space three.js ?

https://codepen.io/Lighty/pen/GRqxvZV

Thanks in advance for your help

update this question

answer is answer https://codepen.io/Lighty/pen/yLJKRZw